# Validation MinLength, but not Required

Tags: asp.net-core

How to create a data field that is not required, but if the string is not empty to have a min and max length requirement.

I have read this [.NET mvc3 validation minimumlength, but not required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13483624/net-mvc3-validation-minimumlength-but-not-required), but it is for .net mvc3 and I thought there could be а new more sophisticated solution.

```
    [MinLength(6, ErrorMessage = "Минимално 6 символа")]
    [StringLength(12, ErrorMessage = "Максимално 12 символа")]
    [Display(Name = nameof(TextResources.Egn), ResourceType = typeof(TextResources))]
    public string ClientIdentifier { get; set; }
```

Comment: Where is this validation happening? Is this at the "controller" level or at some database entity level? If it's some kind of controller validation, take a look at FluentValidations `.When` clause. https://fluentvalidation.net/start#conditions

Comment: @jpgrassi It happens at controller level

Comment: @Venkatesh Sorry, I don't like the idea of throwing exceptions. I have done it with custom attribute, but still haven't find the time to post it here.

Comment: @Xueli Chen I also haven't tried the solution

Comment: @stefan.stt Post your answer as soon as possible

Answer (score 2):

For this condition rather than validating attributes go with the custom method and call that method during the initialisation.

```
   if(!string.Isnullorempty(ClientIdentifier))
   {
             if()//check min and max length

                throw exception
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to change your code like below , the StringLength attribute lets you set the maximum length of a string property, and optionally its minimum length.

```
[StringLength(12, MinimumLength = 6, ErrorMessage = "The field must be a string with a minimumLength of 6 and a maxmumLength of 12")]

[Display(Name = nameof(TextResources.Egn), ResourceType = typeof(TextResources))]
public string ClientIdentifier { get; set; }
```